# Running a ASP.NET MVC 5 project locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

My application is a **reportgenerator** which could be reached through an external IIS. But some of my clients would run this app without installing a local IIS locally.

Is there any opportunity running an **ASP.NET MVC 5** application locally without internet connection and without local IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, you need to port your website to a different type of project.  Websites aren't generally designed to be run locally without a web server, that's what applications are for.

You could open your application's functionality up using WebAPI which can be self hosted using OWIN which allows you to run your application independently of IIS.

If you need users to access a front end in order to run reports, then I highly suggest creating it as a real application - cause this is what they are for.  You can provide a front end to the users so that they can access the functionality of your application locally on their machines without a web server.

It's worth noting that in the next version of Visual Studio release notes, they are [unifying WebAPI and MVC into a single programming model](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-preview-vs#ASP).  I'm not precisely sure what the ramifications of this are, but it might mean that MVC can be self hosted just like WebAPI... but I'm not certain.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to package IIS Express and your site in an installer to deploy everything at once.
But never tryed it

Comment: The OP wants to do it without installing IIS locally.